# Is there a way to execute multiple category tag via NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0

Tags: nunit, categories, bdd, specflow

I can execute single test category tag (e.g: `--where "cat=sanity"`) successfully.

However, I need to execute multiple 'cat' tag via NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0.

e.g: something like `--where "cat=sanity"` and `"cat=smoke"` simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'or' symbol to do this, e.g.

```
nunit3-console mytests.dll --where "cat=sanity || cat=smoke"
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) for more details of what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's the placement of your quotation marks that's messing you up. The `--where` option is followed by three arguments rather than one!

So, if you really want "and", these would all work...

```
--where "cat=sanity and cat=smoke"
--where "cat=sanity && cat=smoke"
--where "cat=sanity & cat=smoke"
```

However, as Chris hints, you most likely mean "or" rather than "and." The above will only run tests with **both** categories. If you want either of them, then any of these will do the job.

```
--where "cat=sanity or cat=smoke"
--where "cat=sanity || cat=smoke"
--where "cat=sanity | cat=smoke"
```